# How to split delimited string to multiple fields in Hive

Tags: hadoop, split, hive, etl

I am looking for a Hive SQL solution to do the following job:
converting delimited string to multiple columns

```
example string: 'a01|b01|c01|...'
expect output:
field1   field2   field3 ... fieldn
a01      b01      c01    ... xxx
```

I knew it can be done by adding the field names, like below script, but I prefer smarter solution that can handle the number n automatically.

```
select 
    split('a01|b01|c01|...', '|')[0] as field1,
    split('a01|b01|c01|...', '|')[1] as field2,
    ...
    split('a01|b01|c01|...', '|')[n] as fieldn
```

All ETL tools come with functions to do the split, but as a tester I need a HQL solution.

Comment: You can load as multiple column by using 'fields delimited by '|'' .Is this not possible in your case.

Comment: `N` cannot be determined automatically. You can should know how many columns are in your data

Comment: @Aman, yes it can be loaded to a table in expected fields, but my situation is QA tester don't have write permission on the UAT server.

Comment: @cricket_007, may be the only solution is write user defined function, otherwise have to keep the old way, thanks.